# Unset dependency on binding to dependency property

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I am trying to bind to a dependency property of my user control from my user control however it doesn't seem to be working as the converter keeps throwing an unset dependency property error

The dependency property

```
   public DateTime? DisplayedDate
    {
        get { return (DateTime?)base.GetValue(DisplayedDateProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(DisplayedDateProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayedDateProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayedDate", typeof(DateTime?), typeof(SideBarUser), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata()
      {
          BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
          DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
      });
```

The XAML Binding

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
     <sys:Int32 x:Key="Test">1</sys:Int32>
     <Converters:DateCountConverter x:Key="DateCountConverter"/>
 </UserControl.Resources>



 <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
            TextAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock.Text> 
               <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DateCountConverter}">
                   <Binding Path="DisplayedDate"   />                        
                   <Binding  Source="{StaticResource Test}"  />
               </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
 </TextBlock>
```

And finally the part it's failing at in the coverter

```
 DateTime date = (DateTime)values[0];
```

All together yields

```
System.InvalidCastException
Specified cast is not valid.
at System.Windows.Data.MultiBindingExpression.TransferValue()
   at System.Windows.Data.MultiBindingExpression.Transfer()
   at System.Windows.Data.MultiBindingExpression.UpdateTarget(Boolean includeInnerBindings)
   at System.Windows.Data.MultiBindingExpression.AttachToContext(Boolean lastChance)
   at System.Windows.Data.MultiBindingExpression.MS.Internal.Data.IDataBindEngineClient.AttachToContext(Boolean lastChance)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.Task.Run(Boolean lastChance)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.Run(Object arg)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.OnLayoutUpdated(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.fireLayoutUpdateEvent()
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
   at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateLayout()
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.SetLayoutSize()
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisualInternal(Visual value)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisual(Visual value)
   at MS.Internal.DeferredHwndSource.ProcessQueue(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

I cannot seem to get this to work for the life of me. Am I missing something? When debugging with another instance of Visual Studio it comes up that it is an Unset Dependency property

Edit:
When I comment out everything and just have

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayedDate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

It works just fine displaying the display date. My confusion level is too great to cope with right now

EDIT EDIT:
Converter code

```
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
      DateTime? date = (DateTime?)values[0];
//ToDo move most of the logic inside AppointmentsViewModel class to handle date filtering
                AppointmentsViewModel MyAppointments  = new AppointmentsViewModel();
                String Count;

                int SelectionType = (int)values[1];
                //Note To Self Make Enum
                switch (SelectionType)
                {
                    case 0:
                      Count =  MyAppointments.Appointments.Where(x => date != null && x.Beginning.HasValue && date.HasValue
                          && x.Beginning.Value.Month == date.Value.Month
                             && x.Beginning.Value.Year  == date.Value.Year ).Count().ToString();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Count = MyAppointments.Appointments.Where(x => date != null && x.Test.HasValue && date.HasValue
                            && x.Test.Value.Month == date.Value.Month
                             && x.Test.Value.Year == date.Value.Year).Count().ToString();
                        break;
                  //ETC
                    default:
                        Count =  MyAppointments.Appointments.Where(x => date != null && x.End.HasValue
                            && date.HasValue && x.End.Value.Month == date.Value.Month
                             && x.End.Value.Year == date.Value.Year).Count().ToString();
                        break;
                }
                return Count;
            }

            public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your converter? It sounds like that is where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code. I had to make some assumptions here, so hopefully I'm correct.

**The converter**

Your converter assumes that it will get 2 values of certain types. You want to be a little careful with that. Especially the first value, which comes from a binding, might be `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` if the binding has not been set yet.

So, you probably want to check if the values are correct before you start doing the actual conversion, for example:

```
if (values.Length != 2 || !(values[0] is DateTime?)|| !(values[1] is int))
{
    return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
}
```

You should not have your converter throw exceptions, because they are treated as uncaught run-time exceptions and will terminate your application unless you have some global exception handler (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782205/should-converter-throw-any-kind-of-exception)).

**The control**

Now, I assume that your `DisplayedDate` property is defined on your `UserControl`. If so, then this line:

```
<TextBlock DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

will set the `DataContext` to this `TextBlock`, so when you later go to retrieve the `DisplayedDate` property, it will not be found. You can fix this in 2 ways:

1) You use the ancestor-lookup binding:

```
"{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:UserControl1}}"
```

Of course, replace `local:UserControl1` with the namespace and name of your control.

2) You define the content of the `UserControl` as a Template instead, then use `{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}`, which will point to the "owner" of the template, in this case, your `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
        TextAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DateCountConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="DisplayedDate"   />
                    <Binding  Source="{StaticResource Test}"  />
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Template>
```

Just put this in your XAML instead of the `<TextBlock>`...`</TextBlock>` part.

Maybe there are some other issues, but testing with a simple converter this worked for me.

Comment: Thanks a ton trying to feel my way around the code and learn as I go along. This is great and definitely gives me something to look into and consider. Out of curiosity would you happen to know why setting the textbox inside of the template allows it to work as opposed to just setting it in it's own container I had it in a stackpanel before?

Comment: If I understand your question right, it's not really about putting the TextBlock in the template - the difference is that it allows you to use `{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}` (instead of `{RelativeSource Self}` which will point you to the control that the current template is for - in this case, your UserControl.